# java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format DROOL compatibility with jdk 11 and Wildfly 15

Tags: java-8, wildfly, drools, java-11

I have my application deployed on wildfly 15 and drool dependency of version 5.1.1.
After upgrading to JDK 11, I am facing the following issue.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at test.ear//org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:260)
    at test.ear//org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:204)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:102)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.resolve(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:851)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:100)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1016)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.getExactMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:771)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.getExactMethod(SourceTypeBinding.java:840)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findExactMethod(Scope.java:893)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getImplicitMethod(Scope.java:1952)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:400)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:314)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:314)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:186)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:447)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:189)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:406)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1131)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1219)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:528)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:759)
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
    at test.ear//org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:351)
    at test.ear//org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at test.ear//org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:389)
    at test.ear//org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:56)
    at test.ear//org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:74)
    at test.ear//org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:677)
    at test.ear//org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:640)
    at test.ear//org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromXml(PackageBuilder.java:307)
    at test.ear//org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:467)
    at test.ear//org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:28)
    at test.ear.integration-engine.jar//com.test.generator.xdrl.DroolsXdrlGenerator.xmlToPackage(DroolsXdrlGenerator.java:334)
    at test.ear.integration-engine.jar//com.test.generator.xdrl.DroolsXdrlGenerator.buildRule(DroolsXdrlGenerator.java:277)
    at test.ear.integration-engine.jar//com.test.generator.xdrl.DroolsXdrlGenerator.generate(DroolsXdrlGenerator.java:210)
    at test.ear.integration-engine.jar//com.test.generator.xdrl.DroolsXdrlGenerator.generate(DroolsXdrlGenerator.java:121)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at test.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at test.ear//org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:254)
    ... 104 more
```

I am not getting any clue how to approach the issue? Is it like i need to upgrade the version of drool?

Whereas it is working fine in jdk 8.

Comment: I am using wildfly 15

Comment: A lot of people have trouble getting Drools 5 to work with Java 8. Java 11 is kind of a stretch. Have you tried updating Drools to something released within the past few years? Like 7?

Comment: No @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i yet not tried. But actually that need a lot of code changes. So just wanted to get some idea if it is due to some generic issue..I will try that.

Comment: @learner you were able to find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Any update on this issue? I have jboss-rules.drools-compiler-4.0.7.jar works fine in Java 8 but got wrong class format error in Java 11.

Comment: I need to update the jboss-rules-drools-compiler version which supports JDK11 and needed to fix a few more thing which I am unable to recall as it was done 2 years back.